# Euler formula for geometric modeling faces, holes

Tags: topology, geometry

I don't know if I'm in the right place to ask this question!

I have two 3D modeling and I want verify the Euler-Poincaré Formula on them that include face,holes, vertex, etc. Anyone knows about that?

[image]
[image: First image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking, but the Euler formula is
V - E + F = 2 (1-g), where g is the number of holes (the genus).
Perhaps you also have cavities? Then look at [this San José State exposition](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/eulerpoincare5.htm).

Comment: That what I want! I want to use those Euler formulas for those 3D objects

Comment: @Ja_cpp if the answer helped you upvote it, and if it solved your problem please consider marking it as correct

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I didn't upvote it. I already know those formulas but my question is how can I apply them